# Input field in a popup if radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sapui5

Is it possible to open a pop up window in HTML5 with input fields, if the user click the "yes" radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is this:

```
$("#active").on("click", function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
    var popUp=prompt("Please enter Something","Something");
    if (popUp!=null){
      alert("You wrote "+popUp);
   }
  }
})
```

Here the functional example.

https://jsfiddle.net/feragon42/vjdrsy5m/